# Add custom quick setting tile to quick setting pane programmatically

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I need to add my custom quick setting tile among the 9 visible quick setting tiles.

I need to do it programmatically rather than selecting Edit -> Dragging my tile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. The user has to be the one doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Well ...  As a 3rd party developer you can't do this. However if you are OEM or affiliated developer then you can. It is just a matter of putting things in SystemUI under QS section.